# "No input file specified." in Two-Application Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've done a wide search but couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

I'm using codeigniter with two applications - one for frontend and one for backend.

My folder tree is like:

- application

  - backend
  - frontend
- system
- index.php
- admin.php

I have written htaccess file as:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I wanted to remove the "index.php" from URL but "admin.php" can stay, it's no problem. It works fine with frontend but when I visit /admin.php/login for example, it return "No input file specified."

In Godaddy hosting I have no problem with this htaccess, but now I must use another hosting company.

Can you please help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure the new hosting is using apache and is processing htaccess files?

Comment: Yes. In frontend, there's no problem.

Comment: With index.php?/$1 you are passing the uri as a QUERY_STRING on index.php. admin.php has neither a PATH_INFO or a QUERY_STRING. Try to make a similar rule fro admin.php in htaccess

Comment: Can you help me further with it bro? I couldn't imagine the structure of htaccess

Answer (score 1):

I have found best way works for me copy the application folder and index.php file and create a new folder in directory called backend You may have to do little tweaking.

application folder
index.php
"backend" folder
"backend / application
"backend / index.php

also add to both config base url "BASE" $config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;

I put in main index.php also copy and paste it into the backend index.php

```
/*
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Base URL
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Attemtps to figure the root web address
 *
 */
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
$base_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$base_url .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
}   
else
{
$base_url = 'http://localhost/';
}

define('BASE_URL', $base_url);

unset($base_url);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but as i said, it works well at godaddy hosting. so i think my application structure is no wrong. i think i only need a htaccess fix.

Comment: If you think its you htaccess I have added another answer with two files I use for htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try This htaccess and visit it this page http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/How-to-Multi-site-CodeIgniter-Set-up or http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```